# Binding a null value to a date field in pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc

Using pyodbc, if I try and execute this code on a date field:

```
cursor.execute('insert into test VALUES (?)', None)
```

... I get `pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [SAS][SAS ODBC Driver][SAS Server]ERROR: Value 1 of VALUES clause 1 does not match the data type of the corresponding column in (-1) (SQLExecDirectW)')`, while if I execute this:

```
cursor.execute('insert into test VALUES (null)')
```

... it works.  Is there another way to be executing this, that means I don't need to check the arguments I'm passing?

Answer (score 2):

In my source (Python 2.71 / pyodbc 2.1.8), with a MS Access base, the following code is OK

```
st_dt=None
sql = 'insert into COM(poste,mydate) values (?,?)'
cursor.execute(sql,'1254',st_dt)
cnxn.commit()
```

Where mydate is a Timestamp column with no default value.